# How to get match value of regex in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I need to get the value of a RegEx match and copy its value into another cell.

The string I need to match against will always be in cell E1 and will always follow this type of pattern:

```
CompanyName/12345 Country Product name (Optional subname) Number CUR 123456
```

I need everything inbetween the 5 and 6 digit numbers, so the following regex gets what I need:

```
\s\w.*\s
```

(Space, one or more word characters, space)

I just don't know how to get the VALUE of this match. I see a lot of `RegEx.Replace` methods on SO but I can't seem to find something that gets me the match value.

Here is my code (using `RegEx.Replace`):

```
Sub GetProdID()
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    On Error Resume Next
    RegEx.Pattern = "\s\w.*\s"

    ActiveWorkseet.Range("E1").Value = RegEx.Replace(ActiveWorkseet.Range("E1").Value, "")
    Next
End Sub
```

How do I just get the value of the match? 
And how would I do this if the string I'm matching is always in one cell?

**Update:** The link provided in the comments led me to the right solution. 
Here is the code edits, thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for help

```
Sub GetProdID()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim Prod As String
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Pattern = "\s\w.*\s"

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(Range("E1"))
    Prod = Trim(matches(0))
    Range("F1").Value = Prod
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to get everything between the first and last spaces? `Country Product name (Optional subname) Number CUR`? That is what your regex does now, also ensuring there is 1 word char after the first whitespace matched. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9o8VFq/1). Your requirements are somewhat different since you say you need to get the substring between a 5- and 6-digit number. What are the *actual* requirements?

Comment: Ok, you can figure that out yourself. Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128681/3832970).

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. I would need Everything within those spaces. So I would need "Country Product name (Optional subname) Number CUR". Basically, I need to strip out everything in the middle of the 5 digit and 6 digit numbers.

Comment: What you say and what you try is different. So, if you just need to know how to obtain the match value, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128681/3832970). Then `Trim()` the value obtained and you are done.

Comment: The problem with these examples is they always se the Regex as `Dim regEx As New RegExp`, but I get an error on `As New RegExp`. This doesn't work.

Comment: Did you have a look at the answer I linked *twice*? It is illustrated there, how to add a reference to the Regex library. Besides, you do not need that if you use `Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`. You just need `If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
        RegxFunc = matches(0).Value
    Else
        RegxFunc = "not matched"
    End If`

Comment: I did look at it, yes, and tried to use it. Remember I am new to VBA and I didn't understand how to use it in my own code since we differ a little. But I did find the answer. Thank you for your help - can you set one of your replies as an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: Sorry, if your question was a bit more complex, I could have posted an answer. You just needed the `.Execute` method example, and it is already posted. No need to duplicate.